Evaluating $\iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 4 x}\left(x^2+y^2\right) d A(x, y)$
I have a question of computing the Integral $$\iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 4 x}\left(x^2+y^2\right) d A(x, y)$$
I use the polar coordinate and notice that $x^2+y^2\leq 4x$ is a circle of radius of 2 centered at $(2,0)$. However, I am not sure about the upper and lower bound of the integral. I first obtain the answer
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^2 r^2\cdot rdr = 8\pi
$$
However, when I look at the picture, I notice that if we go along the circle from the origin through lower half to $(4,0)$ to upper half and finally back to the origin. The angle goes from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, but the radius actually goes from 0 to 4 and from 4 back to 0. With that logic, I should evaluate
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{0}d\theta \int_0^4 r^2\cdot rdr+ \int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta \int_4^0 r^2\cdot rdr = 0
$$
So which answer should be correct?

The bounds in your first method are ok if you're using polar coordinates centered in $(2,0)$

@SineoftheTime Thank you for your reply! So what exactly goes wrong in the second approach?

Note that if you use polar coordinates centered at $(2,0)$, then $x^2+y^2\neq r^2$, so you have to correct the first method

aha! I see, so I actually have $x^2+y^2=4x=4r\cos(\theta)$?

So essentially my second approach is correct, and my first approach should be $$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^2 4r\cos(\theta)\cdot rdr $$

But still, the answer doesn't match

No, that's incorrect. You're not computing a line integral. You have to plug $x=2+r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$. You're integrating a positive function so the result can't be $0$

First method
Using polar coordinates centered in $(2,0)$ you have:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 ((2+r\cos \theta)^2+(r\sin \theta)^2)r\mathrm dr \mathrm d\theta =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2(4+r^2+4r\cos \theta)r \mathrm dr \mathrm d\theta $$
Second method
Using polar coordinates centered in $(0,0)$ you have:
$r^2\le 4r\cos\theta$, namely $r\le 4\cos \theta $. Since the radius is positive, you must have $\cos \theta \ge 0$, so $\theta \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. The bounds are:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{4\cos\theta} r^2 r \mathrm dr \mathrm d\theta $$
Third method
Given a perpendicula axis $z$ that passes through the center, the moment of intertia of the disk with respect to the axis $z$ is $I=\frac12 mr^2$. Using Huygens theorem you have:
$$\iint_D(x^2+y^2) \mathrm dx \mathrm dy=\frac12mr^2+mr^2=\frac32mr^2$$
where $m=\pi r^2$ is the mass of the disk.

HINT
Given that $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, according to the cosine's law, one has:
\begin{align*}
r^{2}(\theta) \leq 2^{2} + 2^{2} - 2\times 2\times 2\cos(\pi - 2\theta) & \Longleftrightarrow r^{2}(\theta) \leq 8 + 8\cos(2\theta)\\
& \Longleftrightarrow r^{2}(\theta) \leq 16\cos^{2}(\theta)\\
& \Longleftrightarrow r(\theta) \leq 4|\cos(\theta)|\\
& \Longleftrightarrow r(\theta) \leq 4\cos(\theta) 
\end{align*}
Consequently, the integral to be solved can be written as:
\begin{align*}
\iint_{x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 4x}(x^{2} + y^{2})\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y & = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{4\cos(\theta)}r^{3}\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?
